# Pandas dataframe how to get data from one time frame to another 1 min time frame in Time series data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to change the Timeseries data from one time period to 1 min time periods for below data

Time Series Data:

```
                       Open     High      Low      Close
DateTime                                               
2019-03-22 09:15:00     1342     1342     1342     1342
2019-03-22 09:15:09     1344     1344     1344     1344
2019-03-22 09:15:12   1344.4   1344.4   1344.4   1344.4
2019-03-22 09:15:17     1345     1345     1345     1345
2019-03-22 09:15:22   1344.4   1345.4   1344.4   1344.4
2019-03-22 09:15:24     1349     1349     1349     1349
2019-03-22 09:15:32     1346     1346     1346     1346
2019-03-22 09:15:36     1346     1346     1346     1346
2019-03-22 09:15:41  1346.25  1346.25  1346.25  1346.25
2019-03-22 09:15:43  1346.25  1346.25  1346.25  1346.25
2019-03-22 09:15:45     1346     1346     1346     1346
2019-03-22 09:15:55  1344.45  1344.45  1344.45  1344.45
2019-03-22 09:16:00   1344.4   1344.4   1344.4   1344.4
```

I would like to have as 1min time frame data. really confused with resample function, to_period...etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have correct OHLC values after the resampling, you need to apply proper aggregation functions (taking `first` for Open, `max` for High, `min` for Low and `last` for Close):

```
df.resample('1T').agg({
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': 'last'})
```

Output:

```
                       Open    High     Low    Close
DateTime                                            
2019-03-22 09:15:00  1342.0  1349.0  1342.0  1344.45
2019-03-22 09:16:00  1344.4  1344.4  1344.4  1344.40
```

Comment: Thanks for input how to for mean and sum

Comment: You can pass `{'column_name': 'mean'}` or `{'column_name': 'sum'}` to the `agg` method (or even do `.agg({'column_name': ['mean', 'sum']})`. Also, if you want to run these functions on all your columns, you can `.agg(['mean', 'sum'])` without specifying the column

Answer (score 0):

Resample returns a Resampler object on which you apply the aggregate function,

```
df.resample('1T').last()

                    Open    High    Low     Close
DateTime                
2019-03-22 09:15:00 1344.45 1344.45 1344.45 1344.45
2019-03-22 09:16:00 1344.40 1344.40 1344.40 1344.40
```

If you only wish to change the period but not aggregate the values, use to_period

```
df.to_period('1T')

                    Open    High    Low     Close
DateTime                
2019-03-22 09:15    1342.00 1342.00 1342.00 1342.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1344.00 1344.00 1344.00 1344.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1344.40 1344.40 1344.40 1344.40
2019-03-22 09:15    1345.00 1345.00 1345.00 1345.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1344.40 1345.40 1344.40 1344.40
2019-03-22 09:15    1349.00 1349.00 1349.00 1349.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1346.00 1346.00 1346.00 1346.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1346.00 1346.00 1346.00 1346.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1346.25 1346.25 1346.25 1346.25
2019-03-22 09:15    1346.25 1346.25 1346.25 1346.25
2019-03-22 09:15    1346.00 1346.00 1346.00 1346.00
2019-03-22 09:15    1344.45 1344.45 1344.45 1344.45
2019-03-22 09:16    1344.40 1344.40 1344.40 1344.40
```